# Cannot invoke with an argument list of type 'protocol'

Tags: swift, swift-protocols

I have a protocol and class,

```
protocol MyProtocol{
    func myProtocolFunc()
}

class MyClass : MyProtocol{
    func myProtocolFunc() {
        print("Hello")
    }
}
```

And two function

```
func func1(_ value: MyProtocol){
    value.myProtocolFunc()
}

func func2<T>(_ value: T) where T : MyProtocol{
    value.myProtocolFunc()
}
```

Call func1 and func2 like this:

```
    let a = MyClass()
    func1(a) //print Hello
    func2(a) //print Hello

    let b = a as MyProtocol
    func1(b) //print hello
    //Why?
    func2(b) //cannot invoke 'func2' with an argument list of type '(MyProtocol)'
```

What is the difference between 'func1' and 'func2' ?

Comment: The issue is that in `func2` the where clause doesn't say `T is of type MyProtocol`, but it says: `T conforms to MyProtocol` and [Protocols don't conform to themselves in Swift](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33112559/protocol-doesnt-conform-to-itself)

Comment: @DávidPásztor But in the case of Class say T: AnyCusotmClass then it means that T is type of AnyCustomClass . How compiler identify that T should be type of particular  class or T should conforms AnyCustomClass ? Please explain if have any idea thanks

Comment: @PrashantTukadiya no, even for classes, `T:CustomClass` means `T is or inherits from CustomClass`. The compiler can differentiate between classes and protocols.